# How to split a string, iterate over it, and output a joined version

Tags: ruby, string, join, split

I am writing a method for encryption. I'm working on a code for `caesar_cipher`. The code I wrote is below:

```
def caesar(string, shift = 0)
  alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a
  letters = string.split("")
  blank = []
  letters.map do |letter|
    blank << alphabet[(alphabet.index(letter) + shift) % alphabet.length]   
  end       
  puts blank.join
end
```

I get this error when I pass a string consisting of more than one word:

```
block in `caesar_cipher': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I understand `tr` can solve my problem if I were to create a class. I have an independent method that works on every angle of `caesar_cipher` except sentences. I cannot get the words to be split, iterated over, and then joined. Any input will help me avoid this.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What is the relation between this code and `caesar_cipher`?

Answer (score 2):

After using the advice from the replies, I was able to adjust my code to the following to make it work for sentences instead of just one word:

```
def caesar(string, shift=0)
alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a
    blank = string.each_char.map do |letter|
    alphabet.include?(letter) ? alphabet[(alphabet.index(letter) + shift) % alphabet.length] : letter
    end
puts blank.join
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of following:

```
(alphabet.index(letter) + shift)
```

in-case of multiple words, for each space `letter = " "`. Now you are doing `alphabet.index(letter)`. Since array `alphabet` has no `" "` element, it returns `nil`, following which you do an addition and get the apt error:

> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Once you understand the source of error, solutions to this depends on your algorithm.

Comment: fully understood NOW that the root of the error was because alphabet.index(letter) becomes nil when letter = " " and then nil gets added to shift and creates the error, and as @Jordan explained above, a simple if else statement was able to cover for the white space.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother splitting/joining words. Just skip enciphering characters that aren't in your alphabet:

```
blank = letters.map do |letter|
  if alphabet.include?(letter)
    alphabet[(alphabet.index(letter) + shift) % alphabet.length]
  else
    letter
  end
end
```

You'll notice that the above code doesn't do `blank << ...`. That would have worked with `each`, but not with `map`. `map` returns a new array with one item corresponding to each item on the original array, so this code just assigns the resulting array to `blank` (which means there's no need to do `blank = []` first).

P.S. Instead of `letters = string.split("")`, use `letters = string.chars` or better yet get rid of `letters` entirely and do `string.each_char.map ...`.

Comment: thanks for the simple yet powerful explanation.  The if else code block covers for the white space, and finally blank.join puts it all back together again.  Also I tweaked the code using string.each_char.map and it eliminated the need for the letters variable.  I fully understand now why my code was only working for one word only.

Comment: ps- I did up vote your answer but you have to wait until I have 15 reputation points for it to show.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As your problem has been identified, let me suggest another way to do the encryption, which will illustrate the use of various Ruby methods that have wide application. I will assume the string to be encrypted contains no upper-case letters and only letters are to be shifted.

**Code**

```
def caesar(str, shift = 0)
  arr = [*'a'..'z']
  mapping = arr.zip(arr.rotate(shift)).to_h
  mapping.default_proc = proc { |h,k| h[k] = k }
  str.gsub(/./, mapping)
end
```

**Example**

```
caesar "the die is cast.", 3
  #=> "wkh glh lv fdvw."
```

**Explanation**

First, for `shift = 3`,

```
arr = [*'a'..'z']
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", 
  #    "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"] 
mapping = arr.zip(arr.rotate(shift)).to_h
  #=> {"a"=>"d", "b"=>"e", "c"=>"f", "d"=>"g", "e"=>"h", "f"=>"i", "g"=>"j",
  #    "h"=>"k", "i"=>"l", "j"=>"m", "k"=>"n", "l"=>"o", "m"=>"p", "n"=>"q",
  #    "o"=>"r", "p"=>"s", "q"=>"t", "r"=>"u", "s"=>"v", "t"=>"w", "u"=>"x",
  #    "v"=>"y", "w"=>"z", "x"=>"a", "y"=>"b", "z"=>"c"}
```

Next we add a default proc to this hash, using [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D):

```
mapping.default_proc = proc { |h,k| h[k] = k }
  # => #<Proc:0x007f8ec8b132b8@(irb):1241>
```

This causes `mapping[k]` to return `k` if `mapping` does not have a key `k`. (Nothing more.) For example,

```
mapping['a'] #=> 'd'
mapping['4'] #=> '4'
mapping['$'] #=> '$'
mapping[' '] #=> ' '
```

I have assumed the unencoded message is one of Caesar's favorite expressions:

```
str = "the die is cast."
```

We use the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash to obtain replacement values. As we wish to consider substituting each character, we need to match on the regex `/./`:

```
str.gsub(/./, mapping)
  #=> "wkh glh lv fdvw."
```

Had we not attached the default proc to the hash, we would have obtained 
`"wkhglhlvfdvw"`.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation on an alternative way to write the encryption code.  However, I was looking for a small tweak in my already written code that would help me understand where I was mistaken.  The thing is I am still starting out with the language and .zip, .rotate and .default_proc are methods which I have not yet fully covered.  The fault lies with me as I did not specify this in my question.  With that being said I have saved your code in a .rb file as an alternate solution, which will serve as an excellent reference point, when I come across these methods.

Comment: ps- I did up vote your answer but you have to wait until I have 15 reputation points for it to show.  Thanks again!

Comment: By way of explanation, I provided my answer only because I thought @shivram had dealt with your question. I figured it might be helpful to some readers as well as to you. I don't claim it is the *best* solution. (Yours is better!).  I just wanted to illustrate the approach. I didn't know if the answer would be beyond the state of your knowledge of Ruby, but figured that if it was, you could return to it later, which is what you said you'll do. Of the methods you mentioned, `zip` is used all the time--you'll be getting to that soon.